# silverlight 4 : Cell merge in datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, cell

I am using the DataGrid of Silverlight toolkit. Now my requirement is to merge cell in some of the row in the datagrid.
Is there any way to do Cell merging in the Datagrid using silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just displaying values from multiple columns in one column it is best to do this by using a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Merged Cols">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column1}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You could also do this through a converter if you want to use the DataGridTextColumn. As a Silverlight converter only supports one value you'd need to send the entire row.

The column definition of the DataGrid would contain

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding={Binding Converter={StaticResource MergedCols}} />
```

You'd need to add the MergedCols converter to your solution and to your resource collection.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <myConverters:MergedColsConverter x:Key="MergedCols" />
```